# how to send the table records from one Database to another by datetime using sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am planning move the table records From one database to another by help of Datetime column in the table, please suggest best approaching methods to perform the task,
because every day table will receive 2000 - 5000 records,so it is becoming huge volume

Example

```
Database (X)
table (xx) 

copy the records from table(xx) of database (X) by fetching 3 months old data by targeting Datetime column in the Table(xx) 

To 

Database(Y)
table(yy)
```

Comment: This question doesn't show much research effort. What have you tried so far and why are you worried that that might not be the best approach?

Comment: 1)in same database we can copy records by creating new table as such 2)by creating two mdf file groups like primary and secondary doing partioning we can perform the task, but now i want copy the records from one db to another db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered an SSIS package? Once you've built it, you can run it manually or schedule it to run on certain time intervals. Here's some material on it and I must admit, it is pretty easy to build, specially for an easy task like you describe.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/207/creating-a-simple-ssis-package/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917(v=sql.105).aspx

http://www.katieandemil.com/create-ssis-package-find-an-example-how-to-create-an-ssis-package-a-simple-one